# Ember JS: How can I practice 'Data Down, Actions Up' with composable helpers?

Tags: ember.js

New to ember and practicing 'Data Down, Actions Up' with composable helpers. Is this possible? This is what I'm attempting to do:

```
//parent template
{{pizza-toppings toggleToppings=(action (toggle 'toppings' this 'mushrooms' 'anchovies'))}}

//child component template
<div {{action "toggleToppings"}}>
```

But I get a 'no action handler for: toggleToppings' error.

So then I tried making an action on the child, like so:

```
//child component template 
<div {{action "togglePizza"}}>

//child component JS
actions: {
   togglePizza() {
          this.get('toggleToppings')();
   }
}
```

But when I click on that, nothing happens at all. :( How can I call my parent action from within my component template?

Comment: your code in child component js looks ok, prob is your `toggleToppings`. Can you define it in parent js file instead?

Comment: Yes, I can definitely do that! Super newbie question: can you define composable actions in the parent JS file? Or should I just use a regular action, instead?

Comment: what do you mean composable action?

Comment: Ah I get what you are doing now, let’s just put the code in js file and see how it goes, composable or not shouldn’t matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the child component template to the following:

```
<div {{action toggleToppings}}>
```

When you use quotes, you are telling handlebars to lookup an action by that name on the actions hash of the current context (and bubble that action up if it is not found).  However, when you pass an action (an action is really just a bound function) into this component from the parent you don't add it to the actions hash, you've just added it as a property on the component's context.

As for why the latter second attempt did not work for you, I suspect it actually does work but that the action handler has some other non-related issue. Adding a debugger to the "toggle" helper will let you know whether and when it is being called.

Comment: To add, I think he needs to add `cursor: pointer;` in the CSS for that `div` tag. See [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.1.0/templates/actions/#toc_attaching-actions-to-non-clickable-elements).

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the clear explanation. Btw, I didn't need to use 'cursor: pointer' as recommended below, but I'll keep that trick in mind next time I have this problem. :)